# How to parse kafka Headers in kafka streams?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am working on a PoC to consume the feed from kafka topic using kafka streams in Java and based on kafka message header value, i need to do different processing based on header value. These headers would be custom headers which would be provided by producer on kafka topic.

We are using kafka 1.1.1 for our PoC and using kafka-streams 1.1.1 version too in my PoC.
I tried to search a lot on internet but could not get concrete.

Comment: See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46738514/5427593) for similar question.

Comment: But it says it is available from streams version 2.0 but i am using 1.1.1 version of streams API.

Comment: Well, than you need to upgrade to 2.0, or even better to 2.4 or 2.5 (that will be release soon). It's not available in older versions like 1.1 if you use the Streams API. If you cannot upgrade to 2.0 or newer, you would need to fall back to the Consumer API to access headers.